# nodejs restful api returning error status -1 at ionic angularjs $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api, http

My ionic angularjs code where I am making a get request looks like this:

```
.factory('Tasks', function($http) {
  return {
    all: function() {
      $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/hello'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    alert(JSON.stringify(response))
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    alert(JSON.stringify(response))
  });

      $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/hello'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    alert(JSON.stringify(response))
  });
 }
}
```

Which alerts following:

```
{"data":null,"status":-1,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"http://localhost:3000/hello","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":""}
```

My nodejs api server looks like following:

```
app.get('/hello', function(req,res){
    res.json({hello: "hi"})

})
```

And my curl:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET localhost:3000/hello
```

Returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
content-type: application/json
content-length: 14
etag: "-1509679108"
Date: Sat, 11 Jun 2016 20:06:29 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{"hello":"hi"}
```

Surprisingly it works fine with this test url:
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Are there any errors getting thrown in console? It could be an issue with cross-origin-headers.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I'm running into the issue now. My requests work fine when I send them from PostMan, but in my app they don't :(